# Should use Kafka Schema Registry server

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

When I used Schema registry server, I found I could not change schema in the same topic anymore. but without schema registry each record has it's own schema inside, so it's easy to change schema anytime.

So how can I change the schema when I'm using schema registry server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change schemas stored in the Confluent Schema Registry, it’s just that the default config enforces backward compatibility. You can change that compatibility config using the following parameter:

```
avro.compatibility.level
```

The Avro compatibility type. Valid values are:

- **`none`** (new schema can be any valid Avro schema),
- **`backward`** (new schema can read data produced by latest registered schema),
- **`backward_transitive`** (new schema can read data produced by all previously registered schemas),
- **`forward`** (latest registered schema can read data produced by the new schema),
- **`forward_transitive`** (all previously registered schemas can read data produced by the new schema),
- **`full`** (new schema is backward and forward compatible with latest registered schema),
- **`full_transitive`** (new schema is backward and forward compatible with all previously registered schemas)

Type: string Default: “backward” Importance: high